# Finding out if a LngLat point is between two other Points

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, vector, latitude-longitude

I am using Google Maps, and trying to find out if a point is between two other points. The way I've been doing it this far is making two vectors. One between the two "check" points, and one between one of the "check" points, and the "new" point. After the vectors have been calculated, i've crossed them, and gotten a cross value.
Then i've done the same for all the "check" points i had, and if the new crossProduct was smaller than the old one, i've sat switched it out.
This has been working soo far, but now i've ran into troubles that this can not solve. So I'm looking for another formular to find out if the point is between the other two points, with a margin of error.

Hope you can help me with this problem

Comment: What do you mean by "BETWEEN" two others ? Do your three points have to be on the same line, or do the "middle" point have to be in a rectangle where NW and SE are coordinates of the two others points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a polyline between the original two points.  Then use the [isLocationOnEdge](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#poly) function to determine if the 3rd point is within a certain number of degrees from your polyline.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Is a point within x degrees of a polyline</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>
<!-- need to load the geometry library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.5003526, -3.0844116);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map, 
            title: "foo"
        });

        var latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.60039, -3.13632);
        var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.36897, -3.07561);

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [latLng1, latLng2],
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map
        });

        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 1));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 0.1));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 0.01));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 0.001));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 0.0001));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(latlng, polyline, 0.00001));
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Doing this I can see my point is within 0.1 degree from my line, but it's not within 0.01 degree of it.  Your tolerance in degrees will vary depending on situation.

Comment: How does the tolerance in degrees work, this is bugging me a lot right now, maybe you can supply a graphic image?

Comment: So there are 360 degrees in the globe.  If you leave that 3rd parameter off, it defaults to 10^-9, i.e. 0.000000001 degree.  The distance of that will vary depending its location on the globe.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees for a better explanation

Comment: Your answer is pretty good, but I can't quite get my example to work.
I've made a demo on JSFiddler, can why doesn't this work?http://jsfiddle.net/rbd3Q/

Comment: That function didn't work at all, but if you can make it work using isLocationOnEdge I would really appreciate it. I read somewhere that one could use containsLocation, but that didn't work for me either. Which ever you can make work I'll use, i've just gone completely still trying to solve this :/ Please help :)

Comment: Code is great. This would have helped if I had more zoomlevels. Do you know of any way to detect the closest polyline?
And I've taken your answer as correct, even though it didn't work in my situation it is still correct :)

Comment: You'd need to work out the distance from your marker to multiple points along your polyline, say every 10 metres.  Repeat for each polyline.  A lot of work (not impossible though)